# Can I prevent single sub-entries in the index?

Tags: indexing

Is it possible to automatically make sub-entries that are the only entry below a main-entry appear with the main entry?

When I currently have

```
Entry1 One ... 11
Entry2
    Two ...... 12
Entry3
    Three .... 13
    Four ..... 14
Entry4 Five .. 15
```

Can I automatically make `Two` appear on its main line, like so?

```
Entry1 One ... 11
Entry2 Two ... 12
Entry3
    Three .... 13
    Four ..... 14
Entry4 Five .. 15
```